# What wireless game controllers are supported by Indigo?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, wireless

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can a microsoft xbox controller be used?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222460/what-wireless-game-controllers-are-supported-by-indigo?/) by [Mike Peel](https://answers.ros.org/users/25323/mike-peel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, if you are using the xbox controller with the wireless adapter, it will work. However, when you connect the wireless usb adapter dongle to your computer, you will actually see 4 joysticks connected (/dev/js0 -- /dev/js3). I believe it should automatically be js0 but you will have to try it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0